# Excel Row paste with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys i need some help on `VBA`.

I have range of numbers in sheet 1 from cells `A6:O29`. Next I have specific numbers selected in Sheet 3 in Column "B".

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I want to loop throw each value in Sheet 3 Column `B` and find that specific value in Sheet 1 range `A6:O29`

Next it should paste Entire Row from Sheet 1 starting From Column (`Q:CF`) in Sheet 3 Starting from Column C onwards

I have coded it but its not working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
Dim main As Worksheet
Dim outcome As Worksheet
    
'main sheet contains Range to search number in
Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
'outcome sheet has specific values in Column B
Set outcome = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
'column B values are considrered as doubles
Dim valuesfind As Double
    
'range where values are to be found 
Dim myrange As Range
    
Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:O29")
    
'no of times to loop code based on values in outcomesheet
locations = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
For i = 6 To locations
  degrees = outcome.Range("B" & i).Value
        
  For b = 6 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            
    If main.Range("A6:O29" & b).Value = degrees Then
      outecome.Range("C:BR" & i).Value = main.Range("Q:CF" & b).Value
      Exit For
    End If
  Next b
Next i
End Sub




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBo66m.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0bRUm.png
```

Comment: "not working" won't help us help you (in fact, "not working" is why you post here..), did an error occured? if so, what error and which line?

Comment: I'm guessing your code is failing here: `If main.Range("A6:O29" & b).Value = degrees Then` and on the following row.  If `b` is equal to 5 then `"A6:O29" & b` will translate to `"A6:O295"`.   You're also trying to set that range to a single value -  the value held by `degrees`.

Comment: Yes exactly, trying to find single value from range as degrees and then want that whole row pasted. we all know it can be done in python with dataframes but i want everything to stay in excel.

Comment: You define a sheet `outcome`, yet you are referring to `outecome.Range("C:BR" & i).Value ....` Actual typo or typo in your question post?

Comment: its in post only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember to declare all variables, add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce it.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
            
    'main sheet contains Range to search number in
    Dim main As Worksheet
    Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Const mainCopyRng As String = "Q?:CF?"
    
    'outcome sheet has specific values in Column B
    Dim outcome As Worksheet
    Set outcome = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Const outcomePasteRng As String = "C?:BR?"
        
    'range where values are to be found
    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = main.Range("A6:O29")
        
    'no of times to loop code based on values in outcomesheet
    Dim outcomeLastRow As Long
    outcomeLastRow = outcome.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
           
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 6 To outcomeLastRow
        Dim Degrees As Double
        Degrees = outcome.Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        Dim searchRng As Range
        Set searchRng = myrange.Find(Degrees, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then
            Dim searchRow As Long
            searchRow = searchRng.Row
            
            outcome.Range(Replace(outcomePasteRng, "?", i)).Value = main.Range(Replace(mainCopyRng, "?", searchRow)).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim main As Worksheet
    Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = main.Range("A6:O29")
    
    Dim outcome As Worksheet
    Set outcome = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    'Set reference to locations in sheet3.
    Dim locations As Range
    With outcome
        Set locations = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    'Search for each location in Sheet1 and if found copy to Sheet3.
    Dim location As Range
    Dim FoundLocation As Range
    For Each location In locations
        Set FoundLocation = myrange.Find( _
            What:=location, _
            After:=myrange.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            
        If Not FoundLocation Is Nothing Then
            main.Cells(FoundLocation.Row, 1).Resize(, 15).Copy _
                Destination:=location.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    Next location
End Sub
```